# ReactJS Calling an API and rendering results

Tags: react.js, jsx

I am currently learning JS Frameworks, right now exploring React and wanted to make sure I keep everything in order, as in: the logic of working with React, code quality, any shortcomings, good/bad practices etc?

The code renders a simple Search panel that will allow to call an API, get the results (if any) and render the results on the page.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

var Style = {
  marginRight: "22px"
};

var Style2 = {
  display: "none"
};

const API_CALL = "xxx";

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      errorValue: "",
      countryCode: "",
      VATNumber: "",
      valid: "",
      name: "",
      address: "",
      isLoading: false,
      isSubmitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  renderField() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label style={Style}>Search VAT:</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} style={Style} />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>Reference: EE100247019</h5>
        {this.renderField()}
        <div id="results" />
        <Loader loading={this.state.isLoading} />
        {this.state.isSubmitted && (
          <Result
            country={this.state.countryCode}
            number={this.state.VATNumber}
            name={this.state.name}
            address={this.state.address}
            error={this.state.errorValue}
            valid={this.state.valid}
            loading={this.state.isLoading}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value.trim() });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, isSubmitted: false });
    Style2 = {
      listStyleType: "none",
      textAlign: "left",
      display: "block",
      border: "1px solid white",
      marginTop: "50px"
    };
    axios
      .get(API_CALL + this.state.value)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          countryCode: res.data.CountryCode,
          VATNumber: res.data.VATNumber,
          name: res.data.Name,
          address: res.data.Address,
          valid: res.data.Valid,
          isLoading: false,
          isSubmitted: true
        })
      )
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({
          valid: false,
          errorValue: this.state.value,
          isLoading: false,
          isSubmitted: true
        })
      );

    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function Loader(props) {
  if (!props.loading) {
    return null;
  }
  return <h6> Loading ... </h6>;
}

function Result(props) {
  if (!props.valid) {
    return (
      <h5>
        Invalid value "{props.error}"
        <br /> <br />
        Please enter valid VAT Number
      </h5>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <table style={Style2}>
        <tr>
          <td>Country code: </td>
          <td>{props.country}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>VAT Number: </td>
          <td>{props.number}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product name: </td>
          <td>{props.name}</td>
        </tr>
        <td>Address: </td>
        <td>{props.address} </td>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: Looks OK; Code sample can be much shorter for this question; Learn react hooks, they are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code after refactor some changes that i think should be good to follow:

1. use let instead of var.
2. I have used style2 as a state as its changing.
3. Used arrow function instead of bind.
4. Prefer destructuring.

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import "./App.css";
> import axios from "axios";
>
> let Style = {
>   marginRight: "22px"
> };
>
> const API_CALL = "xxx";
>
> class SearchForm extends React.Component {
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       value: "",
>       errorValue: "",
>       countryCode: "",
>       VATNumber: "",
>       valid: false,
>       name: "",
>       address: "",
>       isLoading: false,
>       isSubmitted: false,
>       Style2: { display: "none" }
>     };
>   }
>
>   renderField() {
>     return (
>       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
>         <label style={Style}>Search VAT:</label>
>         <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} style={Style} />
>         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
>       </form>
>     );
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     const {
>       Style2 = {},
>       countryCode = "",
>       VATNumber = "",
>       valid = false,
>       name = "",
>       address = "",
>       isLoading = false,
>       isSubmitted = false,
>       errorValue = ""
>     } = this.state;
>     return (
>       <div>
>         <h5>Reference: EE100247019</h5>
>         {this.renderField()}
>         <div id="results" />
>         <Loader loading={isLoading} />
>         {isSubmitted && (
>           <Result
>             country={countryCode}
>             number={VATNumber}
>             name={name}
>             address={address}
>             error={errorValue}
>             valid={valid}
>             loading={isLoading}
>             style={Style2}
>           />
>         )}
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
>
>   handleChange = event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value.trim() });
>
>   handleSubmit = event => {
>     this.setState(({ Style2 }) => ({
>       isLoading: true,
>       isSubmitted: false,
>       Style2: {
>         ...Style2,
>         listStyleType: "none",
>         textAlign: "left",
>         display: "block",
>         border: "1px solid white",
>         marginTop: "50px"
>       }
>     }));
>     axios
>       .get(API_CALL + this.state.value)
>       .then(
>         ({
>           data: {
>             CountryCode = "",
>             VATNumber = "",
>             Name = "",
>             Address = "",
>             Valid = false
>           } = {}
>         } = {}) =>
>           this.setState({
>             countryCode: CountryCode,
>             VATNumber: VATNumber,
>             name: Name,
>             address: Address,
>             valid: Valid,
>             isLoading: false,
>             isSubmitted: true
>           })
>       )
>       .catch(error =>
>         this.setState({
>           valid: false,
>           errorValue: this.state.value,
>           isLoading: false,
>           isSubmitted: true
>         })
>       );
>
>     event.preventDefault();
>   };
> }
>
>
> const Loader = ({ loading = false } = {}) =>
>   loading ? null : <h6> Loading ... </h6>;
>
> const Result = ({
>   valid = false,
>   error = "",
>   style = {},
>   country = "",
>   number = "",
>   name = "",
>   address = ""
> } = {}) => {
>   if (!valid) {
>     return (
>       <h5>
>         Invalid value "{error}"
>         <br /> <br />
>         Please enter valid VAT Number
>       </h5>
>     );
>   } else {
>     return (
>       <table style={style}>
>         <tr>
>           <td>Country code: </td>
>           <td>{country}</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>           <td>VAT Number: </td>
>           <td>{number}</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>           <td>Product name: </td>
>           <td>{name}</td>
>         </tr>
>         <td>Address: </td>
>         <td>{address} </td>
>       </table>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
>
> export default SearchForm;
> ```

Comment: Hi, you should explain why the changes you made to the code makes it better.

Comment: the code follows the best practices that we should follow as asked by @Altair312 in the quesion